# Could this be a bug in the scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs function in Anaconda 2.5.0 environment?

Tags: python, linux, scipy, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue

I am running the scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs function in a Jupyter notebook on a Linux Anaconda 2.5.0 environment but the eigenvalue seems to change every time I run it. When I run the exact same notebook on Mac osX environment, it only gives me one solution for the eigenvalues no matter how many time I run the notebook, which should be the case. Could this possibly be a bug for the scipy package on the Linux system? The notebook I am running is as below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import fftpack as fft
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix, csc_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs, inv

nz = 100
zin = np.arange(nz+1, dtype=np.float64)/nz
N2 = np.full(nz, 1.)
f0 = 1.
beta = 0.
Nx = int(1e2)
Ny = int(1e2)
dx = 1e-1
dy = 1e-1
vbar = np.zeros(nz+1)
ubar = zin
etax = np.zeros(2)
etay = np.zeros(2)
k = fft.fftfreq(Nx, dx)[:Nx/2]
l = fft.fftfreq(Ny, dy)[:Ny/2]

zc = np.hstack(0.5*(zin[1:] + zin[:-1]))
dzc = np.hstack(np.diff(zc))
depth = 1.
dztop = zc[0]
dzbot = depth - zc[-1]
zf = zin
dzf = np.diff(zf)

j = 0

for i in range(len(k)):

    L = lil_matrix((nz+1, nz+1), dtype=np.float64)
    G = L.copy()

    ################
    # n = 0 (surface)
    ################
    R = k[i] * .5*(ubar[0]+ubar[1]) + l[j] * .5*(vbar[0]+vbar[1]) 
    D = dzf[0]**-1
    S = .5 * ( k[i] * ( (ubar[0]-ubar[1])*D - N2[0]/f0 * etay[0] )
                    + l[j] * ( (vbar[0]-vbar[1])*D + N2[0]/f0 * etax[0] ) )

    L[0, 0] = R * D - S
    L[0, 1] = R * (-D) - S
    G[0, 0] = D
    G[0, 1] = - D

    ################
    # n = nz (bottom)
    ################
    R = k[i] * .5*(ubar[nz-1]+ubar[nz]) + l[j] * .5*(vbar[nz-1]+vbar[nz])
    D = dzf[nz-1]**-1
    S = .5 * ( k[i] * ( (ubar[nz-1]-ubar[nz])*D - N2[nz-1]/f0 * etay[1] )
                    + l[j] * ( (vbar[nz-1]-vbar[nz])*D + N2[nz-1]/f0 * etax[1] ) )

    L[nz, nz-1] = R * D - S
    L[nz, nz] = R * (-D) - S
    G[nz, nz-1] = D
    G[nz, nz] = - D

    ################
    # 0 < n < nz (interior)
    ################
    for n in range(1,nz):

        R = k[i] * ubar[n] + l[j] * vbar[n]
        K2 = k[i]**2 + l[j]**2
        bf = f0**2 * dzc[n-1]**-1
        b_1 = N2[n-1] * dzf[n-1]
        b = N2[n] * dzf[n]
        B_1 = bf * b_1**-1
        B = - (bf * ( b**-1 + b_1**-1 ) + K2)
        Bt1 = bf * b**-1

        N2Z = (N2[n]*dzf[n])**-1
        N2Z_1 = (N2[n-1]*dzf[n-1])**-1
        P = ( k[i] * ( beta - bf * ( ubar[n+1] * N2Z
                   - (N2Z + N2Z_1) * ubar[n]
                   + N2Z_1 * ubar[n-1] ) )
                   - l[j] * bf * ( vbar[n+1] * N2Z 
                   - (N2Z + N2Z_1) * vbar[n]
                   + N2Z_1 * vbar[n-1] )
            )

        L[n, n-1] = R * B_1
        L[n, n] = R * B + P
        L[n, n+1] = R * Bt1
        G[n, n-1] = B_1
        G[n, n] = B
        G[n, n+1] = Bt1

    val, func = eigs( csc_matrix(inv(csc_matrix(G)).dot(csc_matrix(L))), 
                                    k=2, which='LI', ncv=100, maxiter=1000 )  # default returns 6 eigenvectors

    if i == 0 and j == 0:
        omega = np.zeros( (len(val), len(k)), dtype=complex )
        psi = np.zeros( (nz+1, len(val), len(k)), dtype=complex )
    omega[:, i] = val
    psi[:, :, i] = func  # Each column is the eigenfunction

omega_imag = omega.imag.max(axis=1)
p = np.argsort(omega_imag)[::-1]
omega = omega[p]
psi = psi[:, p]

print(omega_imag[p])
```

The first time I run this code on the Linux environment, the eigenvalues (i.e. omega_imag) are

```
[ 0.30862832  0.28027858]
```

but the second time gives

```
[ 0.3097162   0.26593829]
```

The environment I am running it in is:

```
# packages in environment at /home/takaya/.conda/envs/oceanmodes:
#
backports                 1.0                      py27_0    defaults
backports-abc             0.4                       <pip>
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0                     <pip>
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.4.0.2                   <pip>
backports_abc             0.4                      py27_0    defaults
cairo                     1.12.18                       6    defaults
configparser              3.5.0b2                  py27_1    defaults
cycler                    0.10.0                   py27_0    defaults
decorator                 4.0.9                    py27_0    defaults
entrypoints               0.2                      py27_1    defaults
fontconfig                2.11.1                        5    defaults
freetype                  2.5.5                         0    defaults
functools32               3.2.3.2                  py27_0    defaults
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py27_0    defaults
ipykernel                 4.3.1                    py27_0    defaults
ipython                   4.2.0                    py27_0    defaults
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py27_0    defaults
ipywidgets                4.1.1                    py27_0    defaults
jinja2                    2.8                      py27_0    defaults
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_2    defaults
jupyter-client            4.2.2                     <pip>
jupyter-console           4.1.1                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.1.0                     <pip>
jupyter_client            4.2.2                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter_console           4.1.1                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.1.0                    py27_0    defaults
libgcc                    5.2.0                         0    defaults
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    defaults
libpng                    1.6.17                        0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.3                         0    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.2                         0    defaults
markupsafe                0.23                     py27_0    <unknown>
matplotlib                1.5.1               np111py27_0    defaults
mistune                   0.7.2                    py27_0    defaults
mkl                       11.3.1                        0    defaults
nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py27_0    defaults
nbformat                  4.0.1                    py27_0    defaults
notebook                  4.2.0                    py27_0    defaults
numpy                     1.11.0                   py27_0    defaults
openssl                   1.0.2h                        0    defaults
path.py                   8.2.1                    py27_0    defaults
pexpect                   4.0.1                    py27_0    defaults
pickleshare               0.5                      py27_0    defaults
pip                       8.1.1                    py27_1    defaults
pixman                    0.32.6                        0    defaults
ptyprocess                0.5                      py27_0    defaults
pycairo                   1.10.0                   py27_0    defaults
pygments                  2.1.3                    py27_0    defaults
pyparsing                 2.1.1                    py27_0    defaults
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py27_1    defaults
python                    2.7.11                        0    defaults
python-dateutil           2.5.2                    py27_0    defaults
pytz                      2016.3                   py27_0    defaults
pyzmq                     15.2.0                   py27_0    defaults
qt                        4.8.7                         1    defaults
qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py27_0    defaults
readline                  6.2                           2    <unknown>
scipy                     0.17.0              np111py27_3    defaults
setuptools                20.7.0                   py27_0    defaults
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_0    defaults
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py27_0    defaults
sip                       4.16.9                   py27_0    defaults
six                       1.10.0                   py27_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.9.2                         0    defaults
ssl_match_hostname        3.4.0.2                  py27_1    defaults
terminado                 0.5                      py27_1    defaults
tk                        8.5.18                        0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/tk-8.5.18-0.tar.bz2
tornado                   4.3                      py27_0    defaults
traitlets                 4.2.1                    py27_0    defaults
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0    defaults
zeromq                    4.1.3                         0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.8                         0    http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/zlib-1.2.8-0.tar.bz2
```

Comment: I'm getting `[ 0.3097162  0.       ]` pretty consistently. Are you using Anaconda? Python2 or Python3?

Comment: That is exactly what I get when running the notebook on Mac osX environment. I am using Anaconda with Python 2.7 on Linux.

Comment: Errr, which versions *precisely*? It might matter here, this looks like pretty strange behavior. Python 2.7.11? Anaconda 2.4?

Comment: I added the environment I'm using above but I'm using Python 2.7.11 and Anaconda 2.5.0

Comment: I didn't even realize Anaconda 2.5.0 was out! I think you've found an honest to goodness bug: you should never see differences between run to run in code that *should* be deterministic.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce with 2.7.11, Linux x86-64, NumPy 0.11.0, SciPy 0.17.0. I get `[ 0.3097162 0. ]` consistently. Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit Python?

Comment: I'm using 64-bit Python. `>>> platform.architecture()
('64bit', 'ELF')`

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Anaconda 2.5.0. I downgraded it to 2.4 and I was able to get the right solutions, i.e. `[ 0.3097162  0.       ]`

Answer (score 1):

The starting vector in ARPACK, if not specified, is random. You can try specifying the `v0` parameter to use a fixed one.

Also, if the computation is sensitive to initial values (ill-conditioned), it is possible to get different results on different runs, due to the fact that floating point rounding error can be affected by external factors which can vary (memory alignment, threading in BLAS etc).

In other words, ensuring deterministic results nowadays requires more than just writing a program and running it --- you may need to compile everything (Numpy, scipy etc) with additional C/Fortran compiler options that produce more strictly deterministic floating-point arithmetic machine code. You may also need to control the use of threads etc. in the optimized linear algera libraries (MKL, Openblas). The easiest option usually is to ensure that the computation is not ill-conditioned so that small perturbations don't matter --- but in the case of ARPACK that's probably not directly under your control, except in the sense that it may be possible to structure the computation you are trying to do in a way where such variations don't matter (or you don't compute the eigenvalues at all).